# How do I get the computer to guess by enumeration?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've only just started using Python so please excuse how bad my code is!

So the computer is playing a game with itself where it has guessed a number between 0 and 100 (target) and it's trying to guess what that number was but it can only guess by enumeration ie. 1,2,3 etc. (i know this isn't the best way for to guess but it's the method I've been asked to show)

This is my code...

```
print "Let's play a game."
print "I'm going to guess a number between 0 and 100. What is it?" #guess by enumeration
from random import randint
target = randint(0, 100)
print "This is the target number,", target
count=0
while True:

    guess=0
    guess+=1
    count+=1
    print guess 
    if guess == target:
        print ("Well done, you got it! It took you", count, "attempts.")

    break
    else:
        print "You didn't get it that time, try again."
```

I'm getting an error when I put this put in. I think there's an issue with the loop and getting the target and guess to equal each other.

This is also the first question I've asked so I'm sorry if this isn't how the questions should be submitted. I'd appreciate any help :-)

Comment: `guess` is set to zero within the loop: you'll get infinite loops most of the time unless target is 1. and if it's 0 you'll never reach it either...

Comment: The `import` line should be placed at the very beginning of your code.

Comment: The error you're getting is because you have code between the `if` and the `else`.  There can't be anything between them

Answer (score 1):

Put the `guess = 0` before your `for` loop: you are reseting `guess` at each iteration.
Also, `count` and `guess` do exactly the same thing, you can just replace one of them by the other.
Finally, the `break` is not correctly indented, it should be at the same level as everything else in this `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

`gess` is always equal to `1` in the while loop, to solve it just move `guess=0` outside:

```
...
guess = 0
while True:
    guess +=1
    ....
```